# Apache Ignite 2.15.0: fixing the GridJettyRestHandler exception

Tags: java, handler, ignite

When running ignite 2.15.0 http rest with spring boot 3 (in a docker image), i'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class
org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.http.jetty.GridJettyRestHandler
does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method
'abstract void handle(java.lang.String,
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request,
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)' of interface
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler. Selected method is 'abstract void
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.handle(java.lang.String,
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request,
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)'.
        at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:563)
        at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$0(HttpChannel.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:762)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:497)
        at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:282)
        at 
org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
        at 
org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
        at 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969)
        at 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194)
        at 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
```

I've looked in the code, it only has method for Javax
(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) and not for the Jakarta
(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) interfaces.
Is there a way to fix the issue? Uses Jakarta instead of Javax?

thank you